# Unable to Get Inline Navbar Inline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html

I've been struggling with this issue for several hours (literally slightly more than 3 hours) and though I know it's something very basic I've been unable, after reading several SO posts and other resources, to determine the problem.

The issue: I cannot get the list items of this navbar to show up inline (to the right of the locationcompletion partial in the below html).

My CSS is, I believe, poorly written, but being green, I started with Bootstrap and then slowly customized the bootstrap classes based on a lot of trial and error. The actual code works fine so it's likely that it's just the CSS between these elements that just doesn't make sense.

Note that the collapsible navbar is working fine and when the resolution triggers the collapse the navbar "button" does show up inline.  It's just when the actual list items show on the non-collapsed navbar that they are not showing inline.

Hopefully I've given you enough code here to assess this.

Thanks for any assistance!

The HTML for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                        </button>
                        <% if ['locations', 'posts'].include?(controller_name) and action_name == 'show' %> 
                                <% if controller_name == 'locations' %>
                                    <%= render 'shared/location_autocompletion', location_name: current_location ? current_location.name : @location.name %>
                                <% else %>
                                    <%= render 'shared/location_autocompletion', location_name: current_location ? current_location.name : @post.location.name %>
                                <% end %>
                        <% else %>
                            <a href="/" class="brand nav">Beelo<sub style="font-size: 8px">ALPHA</sub></a>
                        <% end %>                               
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav pull-right signinout">
                                <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to 'About', page_path('about') %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to 'Terms', page_path('terms') %></li>
                                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                                    <li><%= link_to current_user.username, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                                    <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
                                <% else %>
                                    <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
                                    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                                <% end %>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The HTML/code for the partial that's being called in the navbar HTML:

```
<div class="gplacesboxshow">
  <input id="locationSearchField" class="locationSearchField" type="text" placeholder="Enter a place" size="50", value="<%= location_name %>">
  <%# navigator links %>
  <% if controller_name == 'posts' and action_name == 'show' %> 
    <%#= link_to "Change", new_location_path, class: "btn btn-small" %>
    <%= link_to "View All", location_path(session[:current_location_id] || @post.location_id), class: "btn btn-small" %>
  <% elsif controller_name == 'locations' and action_name == 'show' %>
    <%#= link_to "Change", new_location_path, class: "btn btn-small" %>
    <% if !current_user or !current_user.following_location?(@location.id) %>
      <%= link_to "Follow", follow_location_path(@location), :id => "followlink", :class => "btn btn-small" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_location_path(@location), :id => "followlink", :class => "btn btn-small" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% if controller_name == 'posts' and action_name == 'show' %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= form_for Location.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ref_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :name %>
  <% Location::GOOGLE_PLACES_TYPES.each do |type| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field type %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1%;"></div>
```

The CSS for the navbar and partial:

```
.navbar .nav.pull-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar .nav.showpostnav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 8px 7px 7px 0; 
}

.navbar .nav.pull-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar .nav > ul {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.navbar .nav > li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
  float: none;
  padding: 10px 8px 10px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav.signinout {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container h3 {

}

.container h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

.container h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

#locationSearchField.locationSearchField {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 5px 0 0;
  width: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
     -moz-border-radius: 1px;
          border-radius: 1px;
  padding-left: 2px;
} 

#locationSearchField {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
     -moz-border-radius: 1px;
          border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your site? Or recreate the error in JFiddle?

Comment: MD, thanks for responding. Unfortunately I wasn't yet ready to push those changes to prod so sending the link wouldn't have shown the problem.  I really appreciate you taking a look, though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Amazing how this happens, but once I submitted the question to SO I felt so bad that I couldn't figure it out myself that I took a break, came back to it and, after messing around with it a little bit more, voila:

I did not float the locationsearchfield to the left so when I floated the unordered nav list to the right it was floating relative to a non-floated element.  Once I added the "float: left;" to the locationsearchfield it worked.